# EF Core failed authentication for Postgres in Kubernetes

Tags: c#, postgresql, kubernetes, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Issue is that I can log in PGAdmin, but using the same credentials in .NET Core and trying to run a migration returns wrong credentials. I have also tried to create a super-user from PGAdmin and use those credentials, but it didn't work.

PGSQL and PGAdmin is running on Kubernetes and I have tried two different images - 'postgres' and 'bitnami/postgresql'. For 'posgres' image, I have tried setting different credentials and all of them worked on PGAdmin, but didn't work when running the migration. I have also tried setting 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD' environment variable to 'trust' and this also didn't help. I have tried specifying only 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD' and together with Credentials and it didn't work in both cases for the migrations.

Tried with both variations of connection strings, almost similar, but had to try, because I went out of ideas (tested with and without 'Integrated Security'; tested with IP of the Host, of the cluster and localhost):

```
Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=local_db;User Id=user;Password=password;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;
```

And

```
User ID=user;Password=password;Host=localhost;Database=local_db;Pooling=true;Integrated Security=true
```

The configuration is consisted of two config maps, two deployments and two LoadBalancer services. I am not trying to cover best practices on K8S hosting, I am just trying to make it work. The env variables were successfully loaded in the pods.

Nuget package used: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v5.0.5, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools v5.0.5
.NET used: 5

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pgsql-configmap
data:
  POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: local_db
  POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: user
  POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-configmap
data:
  PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@domain.com
  PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgsql-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pgsql-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgsql-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pgsql-pod-container
        image: bitnami/postgresql:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: pgsql-configmap
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pgsql-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: pgsql-pod
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pgadmin-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgadmin-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pgadmin-pod-container
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: pgadmin-configmap
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: pgadmin-pod
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
```

Exception that I get from the migration:

```
  Exception data:
    Severity: FATAL
    SqlState: 28P01
    MessageText: password authentication failed for user "user"
    File: d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\libpq\auth.c
    Line: 334
    Routine: auth_failed
28P01: password authentication failed for user "user"
```

When the 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD' was set to true and the credentials were removed from the connection string, the error was the following - 'No password has been provided but the backend requires one (in SASL/SCRAM-SHA-256)'. I hope I am not lying about this one, because it happened ones and I've tried a lot of things.

Comment: Try removing Integrated Security=true. Usually you do not mix that when you have a user and password

Comment: @RexHenderson, I have tried this and it didn't work :(

Comment: did you find any solution?